# Conservation of Mechanical Energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

I am currently trying to tackle the problem:

> A 2.0 kg bundle starts up a 30° incline with 125 J of kinetic energy. How far will it slide up the plane if the coefficient of friction is 0.30?

Right now I am stuck on trying to figure out how to get the potential energy and conversion to thermal energy when it gets to the top.

I know that:

Kinetic Energy = Gravitation Potential Energy + Energy From Work (Friction going up the ramp)

I have the amount of kinetic energy but how do I solve for h in (mgh) and solve for d?

Comment: Try a smaller question first. Say it travels up the ramp and gets to a point a vertical distance H above where it started. (1) How far along the ramp did it go? (2) How much work did gravity do? (3) How much work did friction do? In other words, don't start off trying to solve for h. Assume you know that h=H, then answer (1), (2), and (3).

Comment: Okay I assumed that I knew H and came up with the following equation... Ek - Eg = FD -> D = (125 - 19.6H) / (0.3*9.8*sin30). How would I solve for two unknowns though?

Comment: OK, I was going to try to have you do it a different way, but you can do it the way you are suggesting. You have two unknowns, D and H, but so far only one equation. You need another equation. You can get it though, because D is related to H by the geometry of the ramp. So there should be some formula involving D, H, and a sine or a cosine or something like that that you can write down. Then you can plug that equation into the one you have, and solve for H. However your denominator is wrong for two reasons. (1) It doesn't have the right units, you need a mass. (2) Are you sure about sine?

Comment: Okay thanks for the hint and I believe it should be cos now. What units are off? I've used 2kg as the mass and its in the equation.

Comment: F = mu F_N, where F_N is the normal force. You wrote D = (Ek-Eg)/(mu F_N), but then for F_N you just wrote g, you need to include a mass. (You did include it in Eg though).